# Design Package import SharePoint 2013 using App Installed event CSOM

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, client-object-model

In SP2013, I am trying to import and export the design package from one site to other site using AppInstalled event using CSOM.

I am not able to get the context of source site to import the design package from the Solution Gallery of the source site.

Though I am able to pick the design package if I upload it to some location in destination site. But this defets my purpose of automating the process of import of design package from site 1 and install it to site2(where my app will be installed).

Is there any way I can achieve this????